# Embedding static CDATA with its tag in XSLT

Tags: xslt, cdata

I need to output from the XSL a static CDATA construct embedded in the XSL, not from the XML that I am transforming.  For example...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<!-- ================================================== -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Document>
      <text><![CDATA[
<b>static</b>
<br/><br/>
text
<br/><br/>
      ]]>
      </text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//tag"/>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>
<!-- ================================================== -->
  <xsl:template match="tag">
    So on and so forth...
  </xsl:template>
<!-- ================================================== -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want this to output...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<Document>
  <text><![CDATA[
<b>static</b>
<br/><br/>
text
<br/><br/>
  ]]>
  </text>
  So on and so forth...
</Document>
```

But what I get is...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<Document>
  <text>
&lt;b&gt;static&lt;/b&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
text
&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
  </text>
  So on and so forth...
</Document>
```

I've tried several combinations of escaping the text and entities, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="text" />
```

to enforce CDATA for certain elements ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output)).

In any case, what you currently get is equivalent to a CDATA section and it *should* not bother you. (i.e.: If it's bothering you for optical reasons, then get over it. If it is bothering you for technical reasons, fix them.)

Comment: This makes no change in the output.

Comment: 1) The text element is in the XSL not the XML so the cdata-section-elements has no effect.

Comment: 2) Your statement "If it is bothering you for technical reasons, fix them." is just annoying.  I'm outputting in accordance to an external spec, so I do not control the "technical reasons".

Comment: dacracot, which XSLT processor do you use, how do you run the transformation exactly when you say the `xsl:output cdata-section-elements` does not make a change? Do you serialize the transformation result to a file?

Comment: @Martin - I'm using SAXON.  I'm currently debugging using Oxygen.  The "text" tag is not coming from my XML.  It is statically embedded in the XSL, so the xsl:output cdata-section-elements has no affect.

Comment: The `xsl:output cdata-section-elements` tells the processor which elements in the result tree to serialize with CDATA sections as the content so that should work. When I run your sample stylesheet with Tomalak's suggestion added (`<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="text"/>`) it outputs a CDATA section as the contents of the `text` elements. Tested with Saxon 9.3 from the command line.

Comment: @dacracot *"Your statement "If it is bothering you for technical reasons, fix them." is just annoying"* Well, sorry that my answer annoys you. It's not that it would not contain anything helpful. If some application down the line cannot cope with XML (and apparently, that's the case here) then it might be a good idea to get it fixed. That's the point I'm making.

Comment: The cdata-section-elements should have the desired effect provided the XSLT processor is doing the serialization. However, controlling serialization from XSLT is always precarious, because the calling application (e.g. Oxygen) might want to control serialization itself. Unfortunately the spec you are working to is a bad one: it's misguided to mandate that certain things should be in CDATA sections, because the consensus is that CDATA is merely an input convenience, rather like the choice of single or double quotes around attributes, not a way of carrying significant information.